# Using prototype apply vs this to call function

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

On the [MDN String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) page they have an example to polyfill String.includes.

```
String.prototype.includes = function() {'use strict';
    return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
};
```

Is there a reason they used `String.prototype.indexOf.apply` vs calling `indexOf` directly on `this`?

```
String.prototype.includes = function(searchString, position) {'use strict';
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) !== -1;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that the version of the polyfill using `this.indexOf` would not conform to the [spec for `String.prototype.includes`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-string.prototype.includes), which allows `this` to be anything convertible to a string:

> If *searchString* appears as a substring of **the result of converting this object to a String**...

For instance, the `this` to `includes` could be a number:

```
<< String.prototype.includes.call(1, '1')
>> true
```

This is analogous to `String.prototype.indexOf`, which according to [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.7) also does not require its `this` to be a string.

```
<< String.prototype.indexOf.call(1, '1')
>> 0
```

If `includes` is implemented as the OP suggests with `this.indexOf`:

```
String.prototype.includes = function(searchString, position) {'use strict';
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) !== -1;
};
```

Then calling `includes` with a non-string `this`, as allowed by the spec, generates a run-time error:

```
<< String.prototype.includes.call(1, '1')
>> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Whereas the MDN polyfill:

```
String.prototype.includes = function() {'use strict';
    return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
};
```

works correctly, taking advantage of the fact that the `this` for `String.prototype.indexOf` also need not be a string:

```
<< String.prototype.includes.call(1, '1')
>> true
```

So I imagine the MDN polyfill is written that way not to protect against the `indexOf` method being overwritten on some particular string object, or as a shorthand to avoid having to list out parameters, or due to some Crockfordian preference for the `prototype.apply` idiom, but rather in order to correctly implement the spec.

Comment: Then `return String(this).indexOf(searchString, position) !== -1;` will accommodate where *this* is not a String and is consistent with the specification. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Not precisely, because `String(null`) gives you `"null"` and the call would "succeed", whereas `String.prototype.indexOf.call(null, '1')` generates `String.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined` run-time error.

Comment: Who put [*CheckObjectCoercible*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.10) in there? >:-(

Comment: Great explanation and bonus points for directing towards the spec

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a reason to do this. It ensures that even if the `indexOf` property of the string has been overwritten, the original `indexOf` property will still be used.

Such a thing is possible if we use the `new String` constructor.

```
var s = new String('test');
s.indexOf = function() {
    throw new Error('this is bad');
};
s.indexOf('test');//Throws error.
```

Comment: Doesn't this seem a bit odd though.  I mean if you can't trust that normal methods are in place for strings, arrays, etc..., then what can you trust in your environment?  Is one supposed to go `Array.prototype.slice.apply(this, xxx)` just to do a slice() on an array?  Where does the paranoia stop?

Comment: @jfriend00 I hear ya, but Crockford makes this case a lot. It's a good answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree that this is not the most-compelling case to use this, but a polyfill will be used in a completely unknown environment, and the goal is to recreate the functionality as closely and safely as possible.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer to the question, I'm just questioning the code in the question.  I mean, it's probably more likely that the String prototype itself has been tampered with than an individual string object.  Since strings are immutable, most operations on them create new strings making a modification of one particular string object not very useful for very long, so if you wanted to change a string object, you'd probably change the prototype.

Comment: Can you give a reference for your citation of Crockford?

Comment: @jfriend00 True, but if you modify the core functions on the `prototype`, you have broken it for every string instance, however modifying an instance will only break it for that instance. So technically, using `String.prototype.indexOf` can work in more instances.

Comment: torazaburo: You should @JAAulde for that.

Comment: @torazaburo, no, not at the moment. He talked about it and gave the same reason as Alexander's answer in a series of videos, but I can't find them at the moment. The one place I saw him use it a LOT was in his filtering around the block of a for loop using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`. It seems, however, that he may have changed his tune there as the example in the JSLint instructions just shows `foo.hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @JAAulde - when I'm using an object as a map for arbitrary properties (where the keys could be anything), that is one case where it's legit to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` rather than `obj.hasOwnProperty` because if your map contains a key `"hasOwnProperty"`, then `obj.hasOwnProperty()` would not work.

Comment: @jfriend00 ah, that is indeed a better case. Odd that JSLint's instructions don't show it any more.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.indexOf`can take one or two parameters, and using apply allows you to simply pass along what came in, as it came in, without worrying about type or presence checks.

Comment: well you could still do `this.indexOf.apply(this, arguments)`

Comment: Sure, you have a point, although I personally hate the duplicated use of `this` in that line. So I've answered for why to use `apply`, but not why to do it off of `String.prototype`.

Comment: The argument about 2 arguments is weak as well: `this.indexOf(searchString, position);` would be much more readable than a given `.apply()` call

Comment: _shrug_, I disagree that it's weak. If you're augmenting the prototype a lot (as one might do in polyfilling) it's less to juggle over time. Bike shed, I suppose.

Comment: @JAAulde in this particular case nothing can change: 1. arguments of `indexOf` method are known and are not going to change. 2. Arguments of `includes` are known and are not going to change. From your perspective I cannot see how `String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments)` is better than `this.indexOf(searchString, position)`